# Return particular string from response

Tags: python, django

I am trying to return a particular string value after getting response from request URL.
Ex.
response =

```
{
    'assets': [
    {
        'VEG': True,
        'CONTACT': '12345',
        'CLASS': 'SIX',
        'ROLLNO': 'A101',
        'CITY': 'CHANDI',
    }
    ],
    "body": "**Trip**: 2017\r\n** Date**: 15th Jan 2015\r\n**Count**: 501\r\n\r\n"
    }
```

This is the response which i am getting, from this I need only `Date: 15th Jan 2015`. I am not sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a dictionary or a string?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: Cool. Then the answer below should work

Comment: are you in control of what's serving the string? if so, changing the format of the output to conform to json standards would simplify your life immensely, allowing you to just use `json.loads` and move from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming it is a dictionary

`a={'body': '**Trip**: 2017\r\n** Date**: 15th Jan 2015\r\n**Count**: 501\r\n\r\n', 'assets': [{'VEG': True, 'CONTACT': '12345', 'CLASS': 'SIX', 'ROLLNO': 'A101', 'CITY': 'CHANDI'}]}`

then

```
required=a['body'].split('\r\n')[1].replace('**','')
print required
```

result:

```
' Date: 15th Jan 2015'
```

1. Access the key `body` of the dictionary a
2. split through `\r\n` to get a list `['**Trip**: 2017', '** Date**:
       15th Jan 2015', '**Count**: 501', '', '']`
3. access it's first index and replace `**` with empty('')

Answer (score 0):

```
a = str(yourdictionary)
print([e for e in a.split("\r\n") if "Date" in e][0].remove("**").strip())
```

Try this

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, but response is dictionary object.

Comment: That's fine. Just try `str(dictobject)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> body = response['body']
>>> bodylist = body.split('\r\n')
>>> for value in bodylist:
...     value = value.split(':')
...
>>> for i,value in enumerate(bodylist):
...     bodylist[i] = value.split(':')
...
>>> for i, value in enumerate(bodylist):
...     if bodylist[i][0] == '** Date**':
...             print(bodylist[i][1])
...
 15th Jan 2015
```

I have trown it in the interpreter and this works. I don't know if it is the best code around, but it works ;-)